# How to download folder that was previously "Excluded From Path" in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/excluding-files-and-folders-from-upload-download.html) JetBrains documentation, you can easily include a previously excluded folder in your project:

> To get an excluded file or folder involved in upload/download again
>
> Select the file or folder to return to upload/download and choose Remove Path from Excluded on the context menu of the selection.

However, this has not worked for us (on several different computers & projects).

We are able to successfully remove it from the Excluded items, but it does not download the files.

We've tried:

- Re-downloading the specific parent of that folder
- Re-downloading the entire project
- Syncing
- Attempting to grab it through the Remote Host Pane via "Download from Here"

Comment: what is the message error ? Why you downloaded files to local ? IT's strange that delete file into local. Remote perhaps but local I don't understand...

Comment: @darkomen There is no error mesage, it simply does not download the files from the server to local. It treats it like it is still excluded, even though it is clearly marked as being included on the remote host tab (and deployment options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sorted the issue by going to 'Excluded Paths' tab in 'Deployment' window and removing from excluded also local representation of previously excluded remote path. I also needed to create that local local folder to be able to remove it from 'excluded paths' list.

Comment: For me it was enough to exclude it from "Deployment -> Excluded Paths"